# Adding a button in django !

Tags: django-admin

```
 I wanted to add buttons or a url adjacent to "ADD CUSTOMER" button as shown in the image. Please guide me regarding the same.Where should i be making the necessary changes ?
```

please find the image here >> http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/170/query.png

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for posting the question in improper format:

I wanted to add buttons or a url adjacent to "ADD CUSTOMER" button as shown in the image. Please guide me regarding the same.Where should i be making the necessary changes ?

Answer (score 0):

You add buttons/make changes in the html file, or your CSS file if you have one. If you're using Django make the changes in the /templates directory of your project, its the directory that contains the html files.

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you are looking at is the admin site.  The templates for this are located somewhere like "python-path/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/...", but you can override these templates in your project.  I'm not sure how easy it is to do what you're trying to do, but you can see [this link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for more information.